# How to build quarkus native image on google cloudbuild

Tags: maven, quarkus, google-cloud-build, graalvm, cloudbuild.yaml

Does anyone has an idea how to build quarkus native image on cloudbuild?
I use following command to do so:

```
- name: maven:3-jdk-11
    entrypoint: mvn
    args: ["package", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true", "-Pnative", "-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true", "-Dquarkus.container-image.build=true"]
```

Locally everything works fine, but when I try to do it on Google Cloud it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.12.2.Final:build (default) on project fishki: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container runtime was found to run the native image builder
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildContainerRunner.detectContainerRuntime(NativeImageBuildContainerRunner.java:114)
```

My idea is to try to provide the container runtime to run the native image builder, but I have no idea how to do it.

I will appreciate any help, thanks!

**EDIT**:

I use following cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: maven:3-jdk-11
    entrypoint: mvn
    args: ["quarkus:add-extension", "-Dextensions=container-image-docker"]
  - name: docker:latest
  - name: maven:3-jdk-11
    entrypoint: mvn
    args: ["package", "-Pnative", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true", "-Dquarkus.container-image.build=true", "-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true", "-Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker"]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/XXX-XX-XXX/XX-XXX', '.' ]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/XXXX/XXX-XXXX"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy"
    args:
      - run
      - --filename=./deployment.yaml
      - --image=gcr.io/XXX/XXX:latest
      - --location=europe-west1-b
      - --cluster=XX-XXX-XXX-1
```

Now I have a new problem - when I try to install docker container runtime, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.12.2.Final:build (default) on project fishki: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to pull builder image quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.0.0-java11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with this for a while, but the info in the question you asked helped me a lot, so thank you for the ideas which lead me to resolve this issue.

The way I ended up doing it was to build a custom build image like so (`Dockerfile`):

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11
run apt-get update
run apt-get install docker.io -y
run docker --version
```

You can find my build image here (note: mine works with gradle, not maven):
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/lackrobin/quarkus-gradle-build-image

Push this image to the gcr, or any other registry that you can access from google cloud build.

In the `cloudbuild.yaml` file the following configuration should do the trick:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/[link to the builder image above]
    args:
      - addExtension
      - '--extensions=container-image-docker'
      - build
      - '-Dquarkus.package.type=native'
      - '-Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=16g'
      - '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m'
    entrypoint: ./gradlew
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - gcr.io/[project name]/[image name]
      - '-f'
      - src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native
      - .
images:
timeout: 2000s
  - gcr.io/gcr.io/[project name]/[image name]
options:
  machineType: E2_HIGHCPU_32
```

quarkus, or GraalVM uses a lot of resources to build. I had to use a vm with more resources for the build. The command `machineType: E2_HIGHCPU_32` under `options` is responsible for that.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I did it.

I locally prepared this `Dockerfile`:

```
## Stage 1 : build with maven builder image with native capabilities
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:22.2-java17 AS build
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus mvnw /code/mvnw
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus .mvn /code/.mvn
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus pom.xml /code/
USER quarkus
WORKDIR /code
RUN ls -latr ./mvnw
RUN chmod u+x ./mvnw
RUN ./mvnw -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline
RUN ls -latr ./mvnw
COPY src /code/src
RUN ./mvnw package -Pnative -DskipTests -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=7G

## Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-micro-image:1.0
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /code/target/*-runner /work/application

# set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN chmod 775 /work /work/application \
  && chown -R 1001 /work \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /work \
  && chown -R 1001:root /work

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

then this is the `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
# Build for Graal VM tend to take some time.
timeout: '1800s'

steps:
  - name: 'ubuntu'
    script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "=== pwd ==="
      pwd
      echo "=== ls ==="
      ls -latr
      echo "=== ls dockerfiles ==="
      ls -latr src/main/docker      
      echo "=== env ==="
      env

  # Build the native image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '--file', 'src/main/docker/Dockerfile', '--tag', '$_COMPLETE_IMAGE_NAME:develop', '.' ]
    # Build for Graal VM tend to take some time.
    timeout: '1800s'

  # Docker Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - push
      - '$_COMPLETE_IMAGE_NAME:develop'

options:
  machineType: 'E2_HIGHCPU_8'

# Default variables
# https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values
substitutions:
  _DOCKER_IMAGENAME: <the-image-name>
  _DOCKER_REGISTRY: <the-reistry-name>
  _SERVICE_REGION: europe-west1
  _ARTIFACT_REPO: ${_SERVICE_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${_DOCKER_REGISTRY}
  _COMPLETE_IMAGE_NAME: ${_ARTIFACT_REPO}/${_DOCKER_IMAGENAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each build step, Cloud Build executes a docker container as an instance of docker run. What your app requires is the container runtime itself. Therefore you cannot build your container using pre-built Maven builder as the image doesn't have the requirements needed by your app. By looking at Quarkus [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image), you can see that Docker runtime is required to build a native executable.

**Update**: One solution is by creating your own [custom builder](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-community-and-custom-builders#creating_a_custom_builder) where you can set the environment with all the requirements (JDK, Maven, Docker, etc.), and then using it on your build step instead of using a pre-made builder.

See this instructions how to [build containers with a Dockerfile](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers#use-dockerfile).

As additional reference, here's Quarkus [quickstart guide](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/getting-started/src/main/docker).

Comment: I have seen these instructions, but they don't provide an answer for my problem (or I miss something).
Thanks for help.

Comment: @Ksz please see if my updated answer can help you to the right direction

Comment: I feel like I am one step closer to succed, but I have a new problem. Seems like I cannot download docker-builder from inside a cloudbuild environment.